# If I use VS2012 how to host a WCF service in IIS7.0？

Tags: .net, wcf

I am a beginner, if you have time I would very much hope that you can write an article (about host in IIS and WAS), thank you!

Comment: Dude if you google "wcf iis 7 tutorial" you'll find some examples of what your looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following link [Hosting WCF in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042360/hosting-wcf-in-iis-7-5)

1) try to search the site before asking a question, maybe it has been answered as part of another question

2) if not this will help you ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my problem that host WCF service In IIS An error has occurred ----- Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version 3.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089 ', I have resolved, Microsoft has been made ​​on this issue explained（http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751852.aspx），thank you again.